# MFC Ribbon - how can I change the default SMALL Bitmap size?

Tags: bitmap, mfc, size, ribbon

I have started using the MFC Ribbon feature in a new VS 2017 MFC application - and note that the default bitmap sizes that can be used are either 16x16 or 32x32. I am using VS 2015.

I want to assign bitmaps to control button that are a little larger than the standard small size bitmap (e.g. 20x20).  I have prepared a suitable bitmap 'strip' with all my images ready to use - and added it to the existing list of resources with a suitbaly identifying ID (e.g. IDB_WRITESMALL20X20).

BUT when I try to assign the corresponding ID to a Category (any Category!) it won't let me pick that resource from the drop down list.

I'm guessing that the choice of bitmap size is hardcoded somewhere in the MFC library files?

I found a section in 'afxribbonbar.h' file with several 'CSize(16, 16)' entries and changed them to 'CSize(20, 20)'.   BUT this does nothing.

Is there a way to change the choice of small bitmap size without using tsome third party utility (if one exists)?

Comment: The default for small images at 96 dpi display device resolution is 16x16 pixels. You can optionally set alternative bitmaps for other resolutions in the ressource file like so: <Image Source="IDB_WRITESMALL20X20" MinDPI="120" />. But the Ribbon will always decide about the needed size and use/scale the one image that has the closest size to what it needs.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will test it ASAP.  Can you also please clarify if you mean the project .rc file ti be edited?  I ask because I do not see where in the file to place the example instruction line you have given - in particular the stating of the MinDPI.  Thanks again

Comment: usually you will find the ribbon resource file in res\ribbon.mfcribbon-ms.